# I have a large fig tree with the figs rotting and falling off

Tags: figs

As the title states, all the figs fall off the tree without ever getting ripe. I am a property caretaker and the owners said that this happens every year.

It is a huge tree that is full of massive fruit, and I'm wondering if there is anything that can be done. Nobody knows what variety the figs are.

I live in California, zone 9B

We have 3 other Black Mission trees on the property that are all very small, but put out very nice figs, my neighbor has one also.

This tree gets fruit way before the Black Missions, it gets loaded up in March or April and then they sit there on the tree, green, until they all start rotting and dropping around now.

Here's some pictures.

Here's what the green figs look like, they are huge.

[image: Green Figs]
[image]

Here's pictures of the tree and foliage

[image]
[image]

Here's what they look like as they start to rot. The outside gets very soft and squishy, while the inside feels like a hard lump.

[image]
[image]

Here's rotted figs on the ground after they fell. The middle, the flower part, is basically dry.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you cut them open when they are still green, before they get the red on the skin.  There are plenty of figs that ripen green that never turn brown.

Answer (score 1):

My figs ( Anna ?) are fully ripe when they get the slightest blush of red. The animals usually help with harvest long before that. If they were Anna  figs , I would say they were left on the tree a few weeks too long.

Comment: Not enough water